# Increase size of ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

I have been reading all over the internet trying to solve this problem but I have not found a solution to my situation. I am running out of space on my ubuntu partition (dual-boot with windows 10) and I am trying to increase the size of it:

[image: Screenshot]

I have been trying from both ubuntu and windows. Now that I have created an unallocated partition (well, two) I thought I would just be able to increase the size by dragging it. But I am unable to change the size of the ubuntu partition, even decreasing it.

What can I do?

Comment: You cannot change a *mounted* partition...including the partition running Ubuntu. That's what the little 'key' icon is telling you. Boot from a LiveUSB to make the changes. Um, backups before starting are very wise - re-partitioning is inherently risky.

Comment: Yes, just use the same gparted software after booting from a LiveUSB or LiveCD as indicated by @user535733

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to try resizing it in Live Ubuntu mode. Make an Ubuntu bootable USB, and boot from it, selecting `Try Ubuntu without installing`. Since neither of the partitions of the dual-boot will be in use here, they should be easier to resize in the Gparted application (which is included with Live Ubuntu). Just ensure you unmount all the partitions before trying to make any modifications!